# How to query certain document with Firestore Rest API runquery

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore database as below
[My firestore database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnaW8.png)

I would like to query the CASH AND CREDT amount for document 20191003.
I used the below REST api

POST https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/badansales/databases/(default)/documents/sales/20191003:runQuery?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

```
{
 "structuredQuery": {
  "select": {
   "fields": [
    {
     "fieldPath": "CASH"
    },
    {
     "fieldPath": "CREDT"
    }
   ]
  }
 }
}
```

But the response is as below

```
{
 "0": {
  "readTime": "2019-10-04T02:03:57.366908Z"
 }
}
```

Can someone help on this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd advise reading the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api#making_rest_calls which recommends checking out the API Explorer. This can help you create a query.

For your example, maybe try:

```
GET https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/badansales/databases/(default)/documents/sales/20191003?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Notice two things:

- It's a GET and not a POST (there's no alteration of the data here).

Comment: Note that with the REST API `get` method (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/get) you can specify a `mask` Query parameter which specifies the fields to return.

Comment: Thanks! Just updated, pretty cool. I saw the mask in the API Explorer but didn't pay much mind to it.

Comment: Hi, The result I posted actually is from API explorer, but I could not get the fields I want, is that something wrong in my fieldpath?

Comment: I found that https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/badansales/databases/(default)/documents/sales/20191003?key={YOUR_API_KEY} return all the fields value in the document. I don't have to use the runquery api. Thanks